Decision Variables for Pyomo
I have an optimization problem as

I understand that the Pi,t export has to be a decision variable ( it is the objective), but what about the other values? Do we need to consider other P values as decision variables too (because they are on one equation, and changing one impacts the others).
Apologies if this is a simple question but I am really confused.
Thank You!
I tried adding this as an expression in pyomo but don't know whether it is correct.

I don't see this as being a good fit for Stack Overflow; there's no code. Consider instead Operations Research.

Apologies if this is not a good fit, but to code this in pyomo I need to understand the variables first. That is why I posted it here.

OR will give you a better answer in less time. It's more suited to analysis of this kind of problem. Post there.

If I understand you correctly, you’re trying to find out which are the decision variables in your optimization problem. I can confirm that:

An objective function always contains one or more decision variables (otherwise there is no objective).
Decision variables do not necessarily show up in the objective function. In that case they probably effect the values of other decision variables by the equations.
Without fully understanding your specific optimisation problem, the other p variables are likely also decision variables and there are probably more.

Any variables that are not decision variables are parameter variables. These variables should be given a value before the model can be solved. If you’re given input data, these are probably the parameter values.
I use Pyomo expression variables to make my code more readable. They are extremely helpful but not strictly necessary. Instead of defining a really long equation, you can replace parts of the equation as an expression and define that expression elsewhere.
